# Minimal overlap area of circles

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry

I have 20 points in the 2D plane with $(x_i,y_i)$ coordinates.
I want to use *Mathematica* to optimally distribute 10 circles with equal radius of a given positive value $R$, *i.e.* to determine with the optimization 10/20 of the existing points $(x_i,y_i)$ so that the circles area overlap is minimal.

Comment: …and you want to do this with *Mathematica* the software?

Comment: ........Yes. :)

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more details about your plans. What do the points and the circles have to do with each other? Be a bit more specific. Otherwise distribute the circles at x= 0R, 2R, 4R, ... and y= const :p

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data** in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Just to make my question clear, I would like to place the 10 circles with radius R at the already excising (xi,yi) coordinates in the 2D plane. Therefore, the optimization would place the centers of the circles at 10/20 excising points (xi,yi) so that there is minimal overlap between circles areas.

Comment: They are now :)

Comment: The area of overlap for two circles in distance L < 2R is given by 4* integral_(0)^(arccos(L/2R) d\theta L/(8*cos(\theta)). A slow but working version would be to test out all ~184k possible choices, calculate the distances, sum up the overlaps and choose the minimum from a list. I'm positive with a bit of mathematica magic a quicker solution is possible

Comment: You might be able to do something using Mathematica's graph-theory tools.  Construct a weighted graph where two nodes are connected with a weight given by the overlap that their circles would have (and zero weight if they don't overlap.)  Then look for the set of 10 vertices whose induced subgraph has minimal total weight.  Given that there are only ${20 \choose 10} = 184756$ possible vertex subsets, brute-forcing the solution should be possible (though there might be a more elegant way.)  I don't have time to work through this myself just now, unfortunately.

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its likely that the best approaches may come later improving over a previous reply. Therefore, its a good idea to **wait at least 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Answer (score 9):

Brute force approach. Update, now properly using formula for area overlap.
(Note this does not properly handle cases of multiple overlap)

```
(
 points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
 R = .15;
 segarea[R_, L_ ] /; L < 2 R := 
      R^2 ( # - Sin@# ) &@( 2 ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - 1/4 (L/R)^2]] );
 segarea[R_, L_] = 0; 
 x = {#, Total[(segarea[R, Norm[Subtract @@ #]] & /@ 
      Subsets[#, {2}])]} & /@ Subsets[points, {10}];
 minset = MinimalBy[x, #[[2]] &][[1, 1]];
) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 82.0024

```
Graphics[{Circle[#, R] & /@ minset,Point[points],Red,Point[minset]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Brute force

The data

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
```

all the possible 10 [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html) (notice the differences with [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html))

```
allsubsets = Subsets[points, {10}];
```

you can measure the overlapping using [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) and [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html)

```
RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection @@ Thread[Disk[pair, r]]]
```

where `r` is the radius and `pair` the a list with the two coordinates of the [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html)

Now we brute force calculate all the overlaps for all the pairs for all the possible [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html)

```
overlaplist = Table[
   Sum[
    N@RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection @@ Thread[Disk[pair, r]]]
    , {pair, Subsets[subset, {2}]}
    ], {subset, allsubsets}
   ];
```

Or, to find only one of the minima

```
MinimalBy[allsubsets, Sum[
   N@RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection @@ Thread[Disk[pair, 0.3]]]
   , {pair, Subsets[#, {2}]}] &
 , 1
 ]
```

This takes a lot of computation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of the brute-force approach I described above, with the graph theory bit omitted;  it doesn't look like Mathematica has a canned algorithm to find the vertex subset I described.  To save time, the code pre-computes the overlap areas in `adjmat`, and then looks for the sub-matrix of `adjmat` with the lowest sum of its entries.

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
R = 0.15;
overlaparea[u_, v_] := If[EuclideanDistance[u, v] > 2 R || u == v, 0, R^2 ArcCos[EuclideanDistance[u, v]/(2 R)] - (EuclideanDistance[u, v]/2) Sqrt[R^2 - EuclideanDistance[u, v]^2/4]]; 
adjmat = Outer[overlaparea, points, points, 1, 1];
minset = MinimalBy[Subsets[Range[20], {10}], Total[adjmat[[#, #]], 2] &]
Graphics[{Circle[#, R] & /@ points[[First[minset]]], Point[points], Red, Point[points[[First[minset]]]]}]
```

[image]

Thanks to @george2079 for introducing me to `MinimalBy`;  my plotting command is also shamelessly lifted/adapted from his answer.

Comment: Typo fixed.  Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: +1 about 10x faster than mine..

Answer (score 3):

Your data:

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]
```

Find minimum distance:

```
r = Min@Select[EuclideanDistance @@@ Tuples[points, 2], Positive]
```

Graph

```
Graphics@Table[
  Circle[p, r/2]
  , {p, points}
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't see any overlap area calculated? Which are the 10/20 points where the optimization would place the circles centers?

Comment: Got the "complete explanation" after writing the reply. Here the overlap is by definition zero, nothing to optimize.
You should have started by writing more clear question.

Comment: I rather suspect the `R` is a prescribed parameter, not something you can pick to yield a trivial solution..  @HunterItan pleas *edit the question* with a clear description of the problem.